# Strongswan ipsec tunnel not establishing connection with AAA server

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, freeradius

I have two VM

VM-1 : I have installed Strongswan 5.9.

VM-2 : Installed Strongswan 5.9, Installed `freeradius` (radius server)

I have started Strongswan on both VM by `systemctl start strongswan`.

When I run `radtest <username> <password> <ipaddress> <NAS Port> <secretkey>` command from VM-1 request is not authenticated by aaa server, but when I stop `strongswan.service` then I am getting `Received Access-Accept` response from aaa server.

My question is why VM-1 is not able to communicate when `strongswan.service` is active. I guess IPsec tunnel is not established. Below are my `swanctl.conf` file. Can anyone please help here what I am missing. How to establish tunnel and access AAA server.

VM-1

```
connections {

   conn1 {
    local_addrs  = x.x.x.83
    remote_addrs = x.x.x.171

    local {
     auth = psk
     id = x.x.x.83
    }
    remote {
       auth = psk
       id = x.x.x.171
    }
    children {
       vm1-to-aaa {
          local_ts  = x.x.x.83
          remote_ts = x.x.x.171

          start_action = trap
          esp_proposals = aes192gcm16-aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256-modp3072,aes192-sha256-ecp256-modp3072,default
          mode = transport
       }
    }
    version = 2
    mobike = no
    reauth_time = 10800
    proposals = aes192gcm16-aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256-ecp521,aes192-sha256- modp3072,default
 }
}

secrets {
  ike-1 {
    id-1 = x.x.x.83
    id-2 = x.x.x.171
    secret = "thisissecret"
 }
 }
```

VM - 2

```
  connections {

    conn2 {
     local_addrs  = x.x.x.171
     remote_addrs = x.x.x.83

     local {
       auth = psk
       id = x.x.x.171
    }
    remote {
       auth = psk
       id = x.x.x.83
    }
    children {
       aaa-to-vm1 {
          local_ts  = x.x.x.171
          remote_ts = x.x.x.83

          start_action = trap
          esp_proposals = aes192gcm16-aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256-modp3072,aes192-sha256-ecp256-modp3072,default
          mode = transport
       }
    }
    version = 2
    mobike = no
    reauth_time = 10800
    proposals = aes192gcm16-aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256-ecp521,aes192-sha256-modp3072,default
 }
 }

secrets {
  ike-1 {
    id-1 = x.x.x.171
    id-2 = x.x.x.83
    secret = "thisissecret"
 }
}
```

**Update**

When I initiate a command `swanctl -i conn1 -c vm1-to-aaa` I am getting -

```
 [IKE] giving up after 5 retransmits
 [IKE] establishing IKE_SA failed, peer not responding
 initiate failed: establishing CHILD_SA 'vm1-to-aaa' failed
```

Below is my firewall settings -

```
 public (active)
   target: default
   icmp-block-inversion: no
   interfaces: ens32
   sources:
   services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ipsec ssh
   ports: 443/tcp 8765/tcp 8088/tcp 1812/udp 1813/udp 500/udp  4500/udp
   protocols:
   forward: no
   masquerade: yes
   forward-ports:
   source-ports:
   icmp-blocks:
   rich rules:
     rule protocol value="ah" accept
     rule protocol value="esp" accept
```

Comment: Does `swanctl -l` *show* the security association being established on both ends?

Comment: Hi @user1686 `swanctl -l` it is not printing anything.

Comment: What does it show if you try to manually initiate the SA (with `swanctl -i [-i vm1-to-vm2] -c aaa-to-vm1` or something)? What does strongswan.service write to system logs (journalctl -u strongswan -S -1h)? Does your firewall allow ESP packets?

Comment: I have updated the question with logs and firewall settings

Comment: When you do the `swanctl -i` again, does a `tcpdump -n -i any "port 500 or 4500 or esp"` on the answering VM show any inbound IKE packets from the initiating VM? And to be sure, do both vm1 and vm2 _directly_ have external IP addresses, or are they behind any kind of NAT (like the 1:1 NAT that AWS/OCI/GCP use)?

Comment: Packages are coming to VM2. `21:57:31.807413 IP x.x.x.83.isakmp > x.x.x.171.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
21:57:31.810220 IP x.x.x.171.isakmp > x.x.x.83.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[R]`. Those VMs are AWS EC2. DevOps provides only these IPs. What if they behind any NAT? I am not sure on it

Comment: I am trying simple hot-to-host tunneling. Do you think is any issue with `PSK` and algorithm of encryption and decryption

Comment: Probably not -- if that was an issue, the other server would respond with "No proposal chosen". What does the other server write to its system logs? Do the ikev2_init[R] packets show up on _both_ the responder and the initiator?

Comment: Yes. I see `ikev2_init[R]` packets are coming on both VMs

Comment: In that case, either strongswan should react to them and write something to logs, or your firewall is blocking them – can you check journalctl? does ufw enable logging of dropped packets?

Comment: in `journalctl` shows `dropping IKE_SA_INIT response no matching IKE ISA`.

Comment: Hello I was able to establish tunnel. Some other service was also listening on `500/udp` port. Thank you for your `journalctl` hint. One question how can I force freeradius to use ipsec tunnel? or any service installed on that host should validate by ipsec tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dropping IKE_SA_INIT response no matching IKE ISA
>
> Some other service was also listening on 500/udp port

This sounds like you had two different IKE services running (my guess is strongswan-starter and strongswan-swanctl?)

> how can I force freeradius to use ipsec tunnel? or any service installed on that host should validate by ipsec tunnel

The kernel's "transform" (xfrm) policies installed by strongSwan already force this for all outbound traffic. All packets matching the local_ts/remote_ts *traffic selectors* will be automatically transformed (in this case, encrypted in ESP) before being sent out. Either `swanctl -l` or `ip xfrm` will show what policies are active.

(As your local_ts/remote_ts traffic selectors currently specify only IP addresses, *all* traffic between those two hosts will be encrypted. If you want to limit protection to only specific ports, that needs to be added to the traffic selectors.)

You can use iptables or nftables rules to discard *inbound* non-IPsec packets (should they arrive by accident or from unwanted sources):

```
udp dport 1812 meta ipsec exists accept
udp dport 1812 reject
```

```
-p udp --dport 1812 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -j ACCEPT
-p udp --dport 1812 -j REJECT
```

It may be useful to make freeradius.service *depend on* strongswan, so that it won't even start until strongswan has started up (and installed at least the "trap" policies):

```
systemctl add-wants freeradius.service strongswan.service
```